# how can i preview my youtube channel playlist wordpress

Tags: wordpress, youtube

need to preview my YouTube channel playlists on my website page(using WordPress).

[example what need to make the same as this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRJRb.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the default wordpress youtube embeded video dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033662/changing-the-default-wordpress-youtube-embeded-video-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#add_a_channel_section

If it doesn't scroll automatically, **Add a channel section** is where you should check.

Comment: sorry but i don't know how can i do the steps

Comment: Please copy the relevant parts from the link into your answer.  Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the note, I just thought the code in the section was very long to post :)